# “Create new version” ignores custom service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to deploy a new version of a model to AI Platform, it's a custom prediction routine. I've managed to deploy just fine when I have all the resources in the same GCP project, but when I try to deploy and I point the GCS files to a bucket in a different project, it fails to deploy. So I'm trying to pass which service account to use when creating the version, but it keeps ignoring it.

That's the message I get:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[gcp-project-1]/models/[model_name]/versions?alt=json returned "Field: version.deployment_uri Error: The provided GCS prefix [gs://[bucket-gcp-project-2]/] cannot be read by service account service-*****@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'version.deployment_uri', 'description': 'The provided GCS prefix [gs://[bucket-gcp-project-2]/] cannot be read by service account service-******@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com.'}]}]
```

My request looks like

```
POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[gcp-project-1]/models/[model_name]/versions?alt=json

    {
        "name": "v1",
        "deploymentUri": "gs://[bucket-gcp-project-2]",
        "pythonVersion": "3.5",
        "runtimeVersion": "1.13",
        "package_uris": "gs://[bucket-gcp-project-2]/model.tar.gz",
        "predictionClass": "predictor.Predictor",
        "serviceAccount": "my-service-account@[gcp-project-1].iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
```

The service account has access in both projects

Comment: Do the service account have the same Permissions on both projects? Are the [permissions granted at the bucket level](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#bucket_permissions)?

Comment: As I mentioned the service account that I want it to use has permission, but it is ignoring the service account I have specified  (which is the problem I'm trying to solve)

Comment: Please specify which permissions and roles does the `my-service-account@[gcp-project-1].iam.gserviceaccount.com` has in both `project-1` and `project-2`, both on the IAM permissions console and on the bucket level. You can begin by testing giving the service account the Storage Admin role on project-2 at the project level, wait for the permissions to propagate. And afterwards, depending on the specifics of your project you can give finer grain level permissions by using one of these [possibilities](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).

Comment: I think you are missing the point of my question. If you read the error message, it shows which service account is being used, and that's not the one I want it to use. My question is not around permissions, is why it's not using the service account I specified

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a service account is documented as a [beta feature](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/deploying-models). Try using the gcloud SDK, e.g.:

```
gcloud components install beta

gcloud beta ai-platform versions create v1 \
  --service-account my-service-account@[gcp-project-1].iam.gserviceaccount.com ...
```